# Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="[object Object] D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and am trying to implement a scatter chart and my chart is also rendering but I am getting the below error in console.

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="[object Object]  D3.js

My data set is  local variable which is a json object.

Please, check the console of the pen

http://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/LkaKoy?editors=1000

```
var data =[{"date":"0","IPname":"0","stage":"init"},{"date":"1","IPname":"1","stage":"Recon"}];
```

Please help or provide some clue.

Comment: error is coming from svg.append("path").attr("class", "line").attr("d", data). What are you tying to use path for in scatter plot?

Comment: @ChiragKothari, a connected scatter plot is very common in dataviz. To do that, we use a path to connect the circles: http://steveharoz.com/research/connected_scatterplot/

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have a line generator. Add this:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")//change this if you want
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.IPname);
});
```

And then append the path:

```
svg.append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", line(data))
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", "gray");//change the color here
```

Here is your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzEQZR?editors=1000